# "DIE" signal handler for bash

Tags: perl, bash, error-handling

In Perl, you can write a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler to execute code if the program is exiting with an error. Does bash provide similar functionality?

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a bash script that creates a new directory and calls several commands which in turn populates the new directory with data files. I'm using `set -e` so that the script will terminate immediately if any of the commands fail. In case of a failure, I would like the script to remove the directory that it created. If the script completes successfully, then of course the new output should remain.

Does bash provide a DIE signal handler, or any similar functionality that would enable me to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `set -e`, you can install an `ERR` handler:

```
trap errfunc ERR
```

`errfunc` will be called if any command exits with a nonzero exit code (and because you are using `set -e`, this will terminate the script).

You can pass arguments this way, too:

```
trap 'errfunc $LINENO' ERR
```

Since the trap command is `eval`'d at the point of the error, this trap will pass the failing command's line number to `errfunc`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! I forgot to ask: is there any way to pass an argument to the handler function?

Comment: Yes, you can always write `trap 'errfunc arg' ERR`.

Comment: That fixes the argument at the time you define the handler. If you want to pass information about the current state of the program at the time the handler is invoked, you'll have to read from the environment.

Comment: @chepner: Actually, it doesn't fix the argument. The trap command is `eval`'d when the trap executes. Therefore, writing `trap 'errfunc $LINENO' ERR` is a perfectly valid way to get the line number of the failing command.